# href="#anchor" link does not work with clickable jQuery div outside

Tags: jquery, events, html, hyperlink, click

i do have big trouble with sth. i can't get.
i do have

```
<div id="clickable">
  <a href="http://domain.de/link.html">link1</a>
  <a href="http://domain.de/link2.html">link2</a>
  <a href="http://domain.de/me.html#options">anchor link</a>
</div>

jQuery('#clickable').click(function () {
  window.location.href='http://domain.de/link.html';
});
```

link1 and link2 are working fine, but the anchor link calls the div click event

i have tried all the answers regarding bubbling the DOM here on stackoverflow
neither `event.stopPropagation(); return false;` `event.preventDefault();` are working

only with `event.stopPropagation();` i do have the same effect as without anything as seen above

Comment: give the anchors a `display:block;` and use `stopPropagation()`

Comment: not working, still the same issue

Comment: You could add `e` to the handler and do `if (!$(e.target).is('#clickable')) return;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prevent the click event to bubble to the parents of your `<a>` items. e.g. :

```
<div id="clickable">
  <a href="http://domain.de/link.html">link1</a>
  <a href="http://domain.de/link2.html">link2</a>
  <a href="http://domain.de/me.html#options">anchor link</a>
</div>

jQuery('#clickable a').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});

jQuery('#clickable').click(function () {
  window.location.href='http://domain.de/link.html';
});
```